Cannot be added because another seed entity C#
I clone project from repo : https://github.com/trueai-org/module-shop so i migration db with dotnet ef tool but error is:
Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'Shop.Module.Core.Data.ShopDbContext'. The exception 'The seed entity for entity type 'ProductOption' cannot be added because another seed entity
with the same key value for {'Id'} has already been added. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.' was thrown while attem
pting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
how to fix ?
---> System.InvalidOperationException: The seed entity for entity type 'ProductOption' cannot be added because another seed entity with the same key value for {'Id'} has already been a
dded. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateData(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger1 logger) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.ValidateData(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger1 logger)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger1 logger) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger1 logger)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelRuntimeInitializer.Initialize(IModel model, Boolean designTime, IDiagnosticsLogger1 validationLogger) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, ModelCreationDependencies modelCreationDependencies, Boolean designTime) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel(Boolean designTime) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__8_4(IServiceProvider p) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serv
iceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
i change product option has data but not working

new change

modelBuilder.Entity<ProductOption>().HasData(
            new ProductOption
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Color",
                DisplayType = OptionDisplayType.Color,
                CreatedOn = GlobalConfiguration.InitialOn,
                UpdatedOn = GlobalConfiguration.InitialOn
            },
            new ProductOption
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Size",
                CreatedOn = GlobalConfiguration.InitialOn,
                UpdatedOn = GlobalConfiguration.InitialOn
            }
        );


old change

 modelBuilder.Entity<ProductOption>().HasData(
            new ProductOption(1) { Name = "Size", DisplayType = OptionDisplayType.Text },
            new ProductOption(2) { Name = "Color", DisplayType = OptionDisplayType.Color }
        );


entity

public class ProductOption : EntityBase
{
    public ProductOption()
    {
        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public ProductOption(int id) : this()
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    [Required] [StringLength(450)] public string Name { get; set; }

    public OptionDisplayType DisplayType { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
}

